# Is $C([0,1])$ complete if $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$ is the inner product?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inner-products, complete-spaces

One of my homework questions asked me to show that $$(f, g) \mapsto \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$$
defines an inner product on $C([0,1])$, which I was able to do successfully. However, I am curious on whether or not $C([0,1])$ is complete if $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$ is the inner product? I couldn't think of a counterexample, so I assume it is, but what might be a method to show this?

Comment: The completion is $L^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. The norm would be $(\int_0^1 |f|^2)^{1/2}$ and it is easily to find a sequence of continuous functions for which the integral goes to $0$ yet the sequence is not convergent to (continuous) function which is $0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't see how it is easy to find such a sequence. Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: How about $x^n$?

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks for the clarifications. These sort of problems just aren't that intuitive.